Cool identities/properties involving the Alternating Harmonic Numbers
Using the following analytic continuation for the Alternating Harmonic Numbers ($\bar{H}_x=\sum_{i=1}^x\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}i$): $$\bar{H}_x=\ln2+\cos(\pi x)\left(\psi(x)-\psi\left(\frac x2\right)-\frac1x-\ln2\right)$$where $\psi$ is the digamma function, I was able to prove that the fractional part of the roots of this function approach $-\frac1\pi\arctan\left(\frac\pi{\ln2}\right)$ (as they approach $-\infty$). A reflection formula can be derived as well: $$\bar{H}_x-\bar{H}_{2-x}=\pi\cot(\pi x)+\left(\frac1{2-x}-\frac1{1-x}-\frac1x\right)\cos(\pi x)$$Using either the original definition, the analytic continuation, or Euler-Maclaurin definition (it's different from the one given above with its domain only being the positive real numbers) please post an answer with an identity/property for the Alternating Harmonic Numbers. It shouldn't be trivial (i.e. $\bar{H}_x=\bar{H_x}-1+1$ or $0\bar{H}_x=0$) though the proofs of the identities can involve them if needed.

Have you considered using the definition $$\sum _{n=1}^x \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\log (2)-(-1)^x \Phi(-1,1,x+1)$$ where $\Phi$ is the Lerch Transcendent (see WolframAlpha)? There are several identities for the Lerch Transcendent on the Wolfram Function Site.

@StevenClark That's essentially the analytic continuation I used to come up with the identities in OP.

I'll make this answer to show how to find the asymptotic of the roots. We first observe that they must be non-positive. If we take the limit as $x\rightarrow-\infty$ in the reflection formula, we get that $\bar{H}_x-\bar{H}_{2-x}\sim\pi\cot(\pi x)$. Another important observation is that $\bar{H}_{2-x}\rightarrow\ln 2$ at the same time and so $\bar{H}_x\sim\pi\cot(\pi x)+\ln2$. Replacing $x$ with $x_n$, which is defined as the $n$th largest root, we get that $0\sim\pi\cot(\pi x_n)+\ln2$ or $\frac{\ln2}\pi\sim\cot(\pi x_n)$. Using IVT we can prove that there exists a root between the poles of $\bar{H}$, so we get $x_n\sim-n-\frac1{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{\pi}{\ln2}\right)$.
